# Can you actually be arrested for public smoking in Ukraine, like this passage implies?

Tags: historical-context, ukrainian-language, markiyan-kamysh, stalking-the-atomic-city

Chapter 5 of *Stalking the Atomic City* contains the following quote:

> I'm standing at the bus station, in the corner, next to a trash can. That way, the patrol officers won't notice me and arrest me for smoking in a public place.

I'm slightly confused as to why that would prevent the patrol officers from noticing; after all, it seems rather hard to avoid smelling cigarette smoke given its characteristic foul stench.

Also, can you actually be arrested outright for public smoking in Ukraine? Which law is he referring to here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anti-smoking laws in Ukraine were strengthened in 2012, ahead of [a football championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2012) hosted in Ukraine. From [Reuters, 24 May 2012](https://www.reuters.com/article/uk-ukraine-smoking-ban-idUKLNE84N01T20120524):

> Just an ashtray on the table will cost a Ukrainian restaurant or cafe owner a $1,250 fine under an anti-smoking law adopted on Thursday by Ukraine’s parliament, just two weeks before the start of the Euro 2012 soccer championship.
>
> The law, which will bring the former Soviet republic into line with European standards ahead of the month-long Euro-2012 tournament, will ban smoking in all sports buildings, in cafe and restaurants, at bus, tram or train stops, in official buildings and on public transport.
>
> It significantly widened previous 2010 legislation, which prohibits smoking in lifts, hospitals, schools and street underpasses, to include restaurants and cafes.
>
> Until Thursday’s law, restaurant and cafe managers had been able to allocate part of their establishments to smokers, but this will now be banned too.

More details about current legislation can be found at [Alfa Omega](https://alfa-omega.kh.ua/en/ban-of-smoking-in-public-places/), a Ukrainian legal advice firm:

> In accordance with Art. 13 of the Law of Ukraine “On Measures to prevent and reduce tobacco use and its harmful impact on public health,” [...] It prohibits smoking of tobacco products and electronic cigarettes and hookahs:
>
> - in elevators and payphones;
> - on the premises and in the territory of the health institutions;
> - in the buildings and on campus;
> - on the playground;
> - on the premises and in the territory of sports and health and fitness facilities and institutions of physical culture and sports;
> - in the entrances of apartment houses;
> - in the subways;
> - of public transport used for the carriage of passengers;
> - in the premises of institutions of restaurant facilities;
> - in the premises of cultural facilities;
> - in the premises of public authorities and local governments and other public institutions;
> - on the fixed-route bus stops equipped vehicles.
>
> It is forbidden, except in designated smoking areas, smoking tobacco:
>
> - in the premises of enterprises, institutions and organizations of all forms of ownership;
> - in the premises of hotels and similar accommodation citizens;
> - in the premises of the hostels;
> - in airports and train stations.

However, it seems that the penalty for smoking offences is never more than a fine. From the same Alfa Omega source:

> According to Article 175-1 of the Code of Administrative Offences, smoking tobacco products in places where it is prohibited by law, as well as in other places, certain decision of the respective village, settlement, City Council, entails a warning or a fine ranging from three (51 UAH). and ten (170 UAH.) non-taxable minimum incomes of citizens.
>
> Repeated throughout the year committing violations under the first part of this article, of which he had been subjected to administrative penalties, punishable by a fine of ten (170 UAH.) And twenty (340 UAH.) Non-taxable minimum incomes of citizens.
>
> Also, the Ukrainian legislation provides some articles for offenses related to smoking in undesignated places on ships, smoking in cars (including the lobbies) commuter trains in unauthorized smoking areas in trains for local and long-distance traffic, as well as subways, smoking buses, taxis, trolley buses and trams. If you smoke in these places that are subject to special rules.
>
> Part 2 of Article 110 of the Code of Administrative Offences stipulates that smoking in cars (including the lobbies) commuter trains in unauthorized smoking areas in trains for local and long-distance traffic, as well as subways, shall entail a warning or a fine of five ( 85 UAH.) and twenty (340 UAH.) non-taxable minimum incomes of citizens.

> The fine imposed for committing an administrative offense, the offender shall be entered in the establishment of Bank of Ukraine, except for the fine levied on the location of the offense, unless otherwise provided by the legislation of Ukraine.
>
> In accordance with Article 308 of the Code of Administrative Offences, in the case of non-payment by the offender a fine within the term established by part one of Article 307 of the Code of Administrative Offences, the decision to impose a fine is sent for enforcement to the department of state executive service at the place of residence of the offender, work or at the location of its property in the manner prescribed by law.
>
> In order enforcement of the decision to recover the penalty for committing an administrative offense the offender will be charged with:
>
> - Double the size of the fine, as defined in the relevant article of the Code of Administrative Offences and specified in the order for recovery of the fine;
> - Expenditure on account of these offenses. The size of the cost of keeping the offenses defined by the Cabinet of Ministers of Ukraine.

There are some possible translation issues in this text - I'm not sure what "on the fixed-route bus stops equipped vehicles" means, whether it means *on* a vehicle or at a bus stop - but it makes sense that bus stations would be included under this law, in the same way as train stations and public transport.

It may be that "arrested" in your translation of the novel is also an imperfect translation: the officers wouldn't have literally arrested him, but they might have detained him and issued him with an order to pay a fine, either then and there or in a bank later.

Comment: In many languages "to stop someone" and "to arrest someone" is the same word.

Comment: @dotancohen Right, which is why I'm blaming the translation rather than the author for the apparent inaccuracy.